# how use v-show in background of slot:expanded-item in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a table with expanded feature in Vuetify like this :

```
<template v-slot:item="{ item, expand, isExpanded }">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <v-btn @click="expand(!isExpanded)">Expand</v-btn>
    </td>
    <td class="d-block d-sm-table-cell" v-for="field in Object.keys(item)">
      {{item[field]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<template v-slot:expanded-item="{item }">
  <CustomComponent :ref="item.id" />
</template>
```

here , `Vuetify` use v-if in background and it means I have do not have any access to `CustomComponent` when I did not open accordion , while I need it

I found a solution that if `Vuetify` use v-show instead v-if in background , solve my problem

Do you have any idea?

Comment: That's not possible, you cannot change the way Vuetify renders its slots. On the other hand, it should be easy to get rid of the `ref` and work with data/event bindings

Comment: @MoritzRingler I try ref at first but when expands are closed , there is no access to them!